# Easy way to add custom prerequisite in clickonce publish (VS 2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clickonce, setup-deployment

I would like to add Infragistics dlls as custom prerequisite when publishing my project.

I've read about that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730839%28VS.80%29.aspx

But this seems to be a bit complicated...
I wonder if exists a bit simple way to archive that (eg by passing URL to setup.exe or such) ?

**EDIT**
This Might be also interesting: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Add_Custom_Prerequisite.aspx?msg=2520811 will check and let you know...

Comment: That's something Infragistics was supposed to do.  I don't think they did, a bit unsurprising.  RTFM: http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2010.1/CLR2.0/  Ask questions at their support forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy the Infragistics assemblies with ClickOnce just like your application assemblies.

Is there a reason why you want them installed as a prereq?

**Edit**
Files deployed with ClickOnce only get downloaded once.  They will not be downloaded again unless they are updated.  The common point of confusion, however, is that the ClickOnce progress dialog always displays the entire size of the application even if it's only downloading a single file.  If you want to know exactly what is being downloaded, use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).  I'm serious, use Fiddler, it's awesome.

Comment: Reason is - to reduce size of installation files needs to be copied to user. If I include Infragistics DLLs (doing right now actually) size is ~30MBs but application is only 300kb..

Comment: Just playing devil's advocate...the user still has to download the 30MBs whether they're a prereq or part of ClickOnce.  With ClickOnce, files are only downloaded if they have changed so the Infragistics dlls would be only be downloaded one time.  In my ClickOnce experience, prereqs are very difficult to manage.  If you upgrade Infragistics versions, you only need to republish your application if you included them in the ClickOnce install.  If they are a prereq, you have to somehow notify the user that they need to download and install something separate from your application.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Are you sure dlls are downloaded only once? Maybe I'm doing something wrong but in my case user is asked to download all package everytime... (I've marked all Infra dlls as 'Include' under VS' publish option)

Comment: The ClickOnce progress dialog always shows the entire size of the application, even if it's only downloading a single file.  This bug has been around for years and will probably never be fixed.  So, yes, the ClickOnce files will only be downloaded once, unless they change or you upgrade.  If you really want to see what's downloaded, run Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) while you start you app.  If this is the issue, comment back and I'll update my answer.

Comment: You are right! I didnt know about this bug. ClickOnce downloads only changed files indeed! Many thanks - I avoided this prereq hell!